# tail multiple files from server to multiple web clients

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux, tail

I'll try to ask my question as simple as it can be..
I have a server that can be accessed from multiple hosts and multiple clients.
the server has a DB that each row has a file attribute in it.
I want to give each user the option to tail the file every time he wants to.
each user can tail from different tabs different files simultaneously.
Thanks for you answers !

Comment: I suggest you use ssh rather than web client.  Otherwise, to tail you can use some AJAX to add lines at the end of the selected file in user's browser.

Comment: ssh  is not what I'm looking for..I already did it the AJAX way , but I was wondering if there is a faster cleaner way..

Comment: Ok, I do not know how then.

Comment: any other suggestions ?

Comment: well, once the browser has read the answer to its request, I know no other way to go one displaying further content of a growing file than some js (which would go back to the AJAX solution).

Comment: So.. I found a cool npm application called frontail that does exactly what I need..
looks promising. 
https://github.com/mthenw/frontail